# Pycharm terminal show input while typing

Tags: python, pycharm

```
input("Prompt")
```

The above does not show what I'm typing in the terminal. How do I show it while typing?

For example, if I'm typing "Answer..."

Each letter should appear in the commandline as if I was writing into the Python interpreter.

Comment: can not reproduce... python writes `input` to the terminal (tested in pycharm).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: in the Configuration, select "Emulate Python console"